# How to rename resume(.doc) with new name in java 

Tags: java, file-handling, servlet-3.0

```
String oldName = D:\careers.bstalents.com\build\web\uploads\Resume\old.doc;
String newName = D:\careers.bstalents.com\build\web\uploads\Resume\new.doc;

           File newFile = new File(newName);
           File oldFile = new File(oldName);
           boolean rename = oldFile.renameTo(newFile);
           if (rename) {

                    outs.write(formFile.getFileData());
                    outs.close();*/
                    FileOutputStream fileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                    fileOutStream.write(resume.getFileData());
                    fileOutStream.flush();
                    fileOutStream.close();
                }
```

I post my code above please share your views .Here renameTo() method is not able to do this.Is there any problem in code ?

Comment: will u put what error you are getting because its work fine for me..

Comment: When i print rename on console it is returning false,if rename =false then it will not go in if block so i can't write the content in new file.

Comment: maybe your old.doc is still opened by other program ?

Comment: @ Liu Yan ,yes you are right because when i am changing the name manually it is showing this message: The action can't be complete because the file is open in JAVA(TM) Platform SE binary. But i am not able to understand where it is open in my program.

Comment: then @jitendra try to close your program which opened your file and then  try again..:)

Comment: @ Denis Tulskiy  outs is  nothing ,It is in commented part.

Comment: @ Sumit Singh If i closed my program and start it again then renaming work for 1 or 2 times after that renameTo () stop working .

Answer (score 0):

Use [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html):

```java
FileUtils.moveFile(oldName, newName);
```